# Universal object of forgetful functor

Tags: category-theory, functors

Is it true that the forgetful functor $\mathcal{F}:Grp\rightarrow Set$ defined by $(A,+)\mapsto\mathcal{F}(A,+)=A$ and $A\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}B\mapsto \mathcal{F}A\stackrel{\mathcal{F}f}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{F}B$, where $a\mapsto \mathcal{F}f(a)=f(a)$ has as universal object $(\mathbb{Z},1)$?

I have prove it as follows: given $G\in Grp$ and $g\in\mathcal{F}G$, then it exist a unique $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ such that $0\mapsto e$ and $1\mapsto g$. So $\mathcal{F}f(1)=f(1)=g$.

Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Comment: So, you wish to show that every element of a group generates a cyclic subgroup?

Comment: $\mathcal F$ is a somewhat unfortunate naming for this functor. It has a left adjoint, the free group on a set, which is usually called $F$ but I'll call $L$. Given this, your question is then: is $\mathbb Z\cong L(1)$ where $1$ is a singleton set? In other words, is $\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to the free group on one generator?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct.  The unique homomorphism $f$ is just defined by $f(n)=g^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.